# How can I know if a country allows drones?

Tags: air-travel, legal, asia, drones

I will travel to some Asian countries very soon and I would take my DJI drone with me, but I don't know if those countries allow the use of drones in their skies. I'm trying to find the government website of each country and read their internal law, but its very painful and not obvious in most cases.

How can I know this infromation for each country?

Comment: You can  know for sure only via that *painful* way.

Comment: isn't there a forum of people who's already travelled with thier drones to a specific countries for example ?

Comment: Asia has quite a number of countries. Unless you list some it’s just going to a wild guess where to look for.

Comment: Besides needing to know whether drones are allowed at all, you will need to know where and under which conditions drones are allowed in each of the countries. Like how close to airports, military installations and houses and at what levels. Easier to assume you can not use your drone at all.

Comment: I m not sure if I can give you the entire list. I can say philipine china and japan, for the rest it's not definitive.

Comment: @HankyPanky There are quite a number of fish in the ocean, but if someone asks 'How do I catch fish' I'd bet most people could offer some decent general advice.

Comment: Also take a look at airline restrictions on lithium/LiPo battery packs.  Some have size restrictions, carry-on vs checked bags rules, etc.

Comment: Do people in those countries like drones? Do those drone enthusiasts have internet forums?  I would expect them to be thrilled to help out a visitor if the language barrier can be conquered...

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland failing to catch a fish is a mere disappointment and loss of pleasure but failing to obey laws of foreign countries when there means a lot more than that. If I were to advise OP that it’s generally possible in Asia only for OP to end up in a country where it gets confiscated I wouldn’t think of my advice as decent. My advice would still be to research individual countries by name where the OP intends to go.

Comment: @Harper, I think it's tricky to find all forums which talk about internal law and the drones restrictions if we consider the nombre of languges talking around the world

Answer (score 11):

This site lists drone laws by country:

https://uavsystemsinternational.com/pages/drone-laws-by-country

It should be able to give you any known laws. However, I would still be sure to declare them wherever you go, just because of the political climate these days...

Comment: After choosing a country from a site like that, I would confirm with a query to “someone who should know” in that country.  Websites, including government websites, aren’t always current.  And people who should know might not.  (Lawyers in Spain frequently misrepresent or oversimplify the actual law about residence and taxes.)

Answer (score 2):

There are websites that list drone laws by country.

For example, [UAV Coach](https://uavcoach.com/drone-laws/) lists laws by state and country around the world.