# Can i take my drone to Lombok and fly there?

Tags: international-travel, lombok, drones

In 2 months I will be going to Lombok. I have a DJI Mavic Air Drone and would like to take it to Lombok. Is this possible? What about the airline (Singapore Air), can I take it in my hand luggage?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112261/how-can-i-know-if-a-country-allows-drones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I had to look this up, it confirmed my gut feeling that recreational use of drones within Indonesia was fine.

[Indonesia Drone Laws](https://www.uavsystemsinternational.com/drone-laws-by-country/indonesia-drone-laws/)

There are some common sense restrictions listed in the link.  The only ones that stood out for me were:

- Don't fly over temples (I'd suggest not near either)
- Use common sense and don't fly over crowds
- Ensure you are nowhere near a government facility
- Stay below 150m
- Only fly during daylight

Drones should be fine in hand luggage.  The weight and dimensions of your drone should be fine, but ensure all batteries are appropriately packaged for flight.